# Drupal 7 Views - loop into $fields and get the content

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

So far, I have done the following things.

1 - created a view i called it (vue-du-galerie) with three fields (field_galerie_image,field__galerie_description,title)

2 - Created a custom theme as 'views-view-fields--vue-du-galerie.tpl.php'

3 - The block is working without a problem.

the html markup of the three fields :

```
        <div class="content-block-contact content-block-gallerie">
            <section class="slider">
                <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                    <!--(from here)loop between all the image fields -->
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/6.png" /> <!--field_galerie_image-->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/6.png" /> <!--field_galerie_image-->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/6.png" /><!--field_galerie_image-->
                        </li>
                    <!--(to here)-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                    <ul class="slides">
                    <!--(from here)loop between all the fields and make them like this -->
                        <li>
                            <div class="field-image-gallerie"><img src="images/6.png" /><!--field_galerie_image--></div>
                            <div class="field-titre-gallerie"><h1>Thématique 1<!--title--></h1></div>
                            <div class="field-description-gallerie"><p>Lorem upsom dolor i,setLorem Lorem upsom dolor i,set <!--field__galerie_descriptiont-->n</p></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="field-image-gallerie"><img src="images/6.png" /><!--field_galerie_image--></div>
                            <div class="field-titre-gallerie"><h1>Thématique 1<!--title--></h1></div>
                            <div class="field-description-gallerie"><p>Lorem upsom dolor i,setLorem Lorem upsom dolor i,se <!--field__galerie_descriptiont--></p></div>
                        </li>
                    <!--(to here)-->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
```

i tried this code in views-view-fields--vue-du-galerie.tpl.php but it it"s not working :

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
            <li>
                <?php print $field['field_galerie_image']->content; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
            <li>
                <div class="field-image-gallerie"><?php print $field['field_galerie_image']->content; ?></div>
                <div class="field-titre-gallerie"><h1><?php print $title; ?></h1></div>
                <div class="field-description-gallerie"><p><?php print $field['field__galerie_description']->content; ?></p></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `$field['YOUR_FIELD']->content` is printing fields data with the extra markup added by views module.

If that is the case, make sure that your view is printing only the field markup without any wrapper elements. From your view administration page `admin/structure/views/view/VIEW_ID` loop through all your fields.

From `Style settings`; check `Customize field HTML` and `Customize field and label wrapper HTML`, and change the value of `HTML element` to `- None -`.